# how can i determine number of threads when using GPU on OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gpu, gpuimage

I'm using OpenCV and VB C++ to run my code on GPU
my GPU device has 96 cores, and I have my code using OpenCV and run on it 
but my problem with threads, I want to determine the number of thread so that the code is executed once on 8 threads, once on 16 threads and so on if that impossible on GPU OpenCV can I determine the number of cores that used on execution.
anyone can help me

Comment: How exactly are you using OpenCV to take advantage of GPU? IIRC there are several different approaches. Which version of OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i determine number of threads when using GPU on OpenCV?

1. First check number of processor in your system
2. Check size of memory in your system.

Now ideally Number of thread should be = number of processor X 2

So if you have 2 processor your can go for 4 thread for best performance.

Also stack size of a thread also plays very important role. Check the size of your memory in the system and set the size of stack of each thread. This calculation is also depends on number of thread you are creating.